# Should I loop or create a function for these commands?

Tags: r, loops, rstudio, lapply, data-cleaning

Hi I'm pretty new to data cleaning in R but super familiar with it in Stata and I'm using RStudio to clean up some data. I'm looking for a way to cut down on the amount of code that I use and I think the way to do this would be to create a loop.

Originally I have:

```
st_complete$accept_d <- as.Date(as.character(st_complete$accept_d), "%Y-%m-%d")
st_complete_07 <- subset(st_complete, accept_d < as.Date("2008-01-01") )
st_complete_07_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete_07)
st_complete_08 <- subset(st_complete, (accept_d < as.Date("2009-01-01") & 
                    accept_d >= as.Date("2008-01-01") ))
st_complete_08_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete_08)
st_complete_09 <- subset(st_complete, (accept_d < as.Date("2010-01-01") & 
 accept_d >= as.Date("2009-01-01") ))
st_complete_09_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete_09)
st_complete_10 <- subset(st_complete, (accept_d < as.Date("2011-01-01") & 
          accept_d >= as.Date("2010-01-01") ))
st_complete_10_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete_10)
st_complete_11 <- subset(st_complete, (accept_d < as.Date("2012-01-01") &
        accept_d >= as.Date("2011-01-01") ))
st_complete_11_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete_11)`
```

So I think every other line (`st_complete_XX_dt` where XX is a 2 digit year) starting with line 3 can be placed into a loop. So I tried:

```
st_complete_yr <- list("st_complete_07", "st_complete_08", "st_complete_09", 
    "st_complete_10", "st_complete_11")`

for (i in str_complete_yr){
  dt_$i <- as.data.table($i)  
}
```

But this isn't working.. I think I need to use lapply since `st_complete_yr` is a list but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: perhaps something like `st_complete_x_dt <- function(x) {
  res <- subset(st_complete, year(accept_d) == x); as.data.table(res)
}`

Comment: You should ask yourself why you are creating these subsets and if it is really necessary to store them as separate objects (probably not). Also, you use package data.table, but don't use data.table operations/syntax, which suggests that you haven't understood the package yet (dangerous) and aren't using its full potential.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
library(data.table)
dates <- seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), length.out=5, by='1 year')
st_complete_07_dt <- setDT(subset(st_complete, accept_d < 
                                       as.Date("2008-01-01")))
lst <- Map( function(x,y) setDT(subset(st_complete, 
     accept_d < y & accept_d >= x)),dates[-length(dates)], dates[-1])
lst <- c(list(st_complete_07_dt), lst)

names(lst) <- sprintf('st_complete_%02d_dt', 7:11)
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)

head(st_complete_08_dt,2)
#    accept_d        Col2
#1: 2008-08-08 -0.02063172
#2: 2008-03-25 -0.90366751
```

Or you could do

```
st_complete_dt <- as.data.table(st_complete)
setkey(st_complete_dt, accept_d)
lstN <- st_complete_dt[,year:=format(accept_d, '%Y')][year<2008,
                  year:='<2008'][, list(list(.SD)), by=year]$V1
names(lstN) <- sprintf('st_complete_%02d_dt', 7:11)
list2env(lstN, envir=.GlobalEnv)
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
head(st_complete_08_dt,2)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
st_complete <- data.frame(accept_d = sample(seq(as.Date('2007-01-01'), 
          length.out=2000, by='1 day'), 400, replace=FALSE), Col2=rnorm(400))
```